# Angular, obtener elemento de un Array en JSON

Tags: angular

Esta funcion obtiene un array en JSON de un servicio:

```
public dias: DiasSemana;

getDias(){ 
  this.pendientesServicio.getDias()
   .subscribe( (respuesta:DiasSemana) => {
     this.dias = respuesta;
   });
}
```

Algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito obtener un elemento de cada fila devuelta, en mi caso **"id_pendi_dias"**, pero si lo llamo así me devuelve null. Cómo puedo obtener ese elemento?

```
getDias(){ 
  this.pendientesServicio.getDias()
   .subscribe( (respuesta:DiasSemana) => {
     this.dias = respuesta;
     this.dias.id_pendi_dias;
   });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que `this.dias` es un `Array`, para acceder a sus elementos debes indicar el índice del mismo. Para recorrer el `Array` puedes hacer varias cosas, si necesitas solamente el campo `id_pendi_dias` de cada elemento de tu `Array`, puedes crear un nuevo `Array` a partir del que ya tienes cuyos elementos sean los valores de `id_pendi_dias` de cada elemento.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const resultado = [
  {0: null, id_pendi_dias: '1', pendi_dia: 'Lunes', pendi_definicion: 'WORKPLACE OPERATIONS'},
  {0: null, id_pendi_dias: '2', pendi_dia: 'Martes', pendi_definicion: 'WORKPLACE OPERATIONS'},
  {0: null, id_pendi_dias: '3', pendi_dia: 'Miercoles', pendi_definicion: 'WORKPLACE OPERATIONS'},
  {0: null, id_pendi_dias: '4', pendi_dia: 'Jueves', pendi_definicion: 'WORKPLACE OPERATIONS'}
]

let idPendiDias = resultado.map(element => {
  return element.id_pendi_dias;
});

console.log(idPendiDias);

// si deseo un elemento en particular:

console.log(resultado[2].id_pendi_dias);
```

En tu código estás intentando hacer:

```
resultado.id_pendi_dias;
```

lo cual devolverá `undefined` ya que estás solicitando una propiedad (`ide_pendi_dias`) a un tipo `Array`, y los tipo `Array` no tienen esta propiedad. Es el elemento de dicho `Array` el que si tiene la propiedad. Y todo elemento de un `Array` se obtiene indicando el índice de su posición en el `Array`.

Espero que esto aclare tu duda.

Comment: Sí, más o menos ya lo entiendo. Sin embargo, no sé cómo mostrarlo en el ngFor, sería algo como  <div *ngFor="let elem of element">{{let.id_pendi_dias}}</div>??

Comment: No, sería algo así: `<div *ngFor="let elem of elements">{{elem.id_pendi_dias}}</div>`. Siempre que `elements` se tu `Array` tal como dices que lo recibes. Saludos